# ionic blank screen with the run command

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been developing an app with ionic for a week with the

```
//working flawlessly
ionic run --device --livereload --consolelogs
```

and it has been flawless the whole time since I started to remove the last 2 arguments

```
//blank screen of death
ionic run --device
```

(ionic serve is working well too, without console errors)

After the splashscreen, it's now giving me a blank screen without any errors in the console and i've been debugging this for the last 6 hours without success. I know there's plenty of solutions out there but none of them seems to work for me.

Seems like --livereload is feeding the root www folder while the default run command is feeding the platforms folder www (maybe that's a clue).

Here's my ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I just found out my problem. Apparently loading librairies from a CDN was the problem. Just downloaded all CDN's librairies that I was using into the lib folder and everything is now loading fine.

Comment: from where can I install CDN libs and how ??

Comment: either download them from the CDN and host them locally or download them via npm I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you have a `<base href="/">` in your index.html, which allows livereload to work but prevents bundled apps from loading files.